# How can I use Torify for an App on OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, proxy, tor

I want one of my applications to use Tor; however the app itself does not have proxy setting and it uses the System proxy. The problem is that I don't want to set my system proxy and I just want this one application to use tor.

I searched a bit for a solution, I came up with `torify`. I have installed `tor` and `torify` using `brew` and everything works fine and for example I can force `curl` to use `tor` like this: `torify curl ifconfig.me 2`

To use `torify`, I need to start my app from Terminal. For this, I use `open -a myapp`. However, this does not make `myapp` to go behind the tor proxy.I think it's because of the `open` command and I think I have to open `myapp` somehow directly. By the way, `myapp` does not work when I try to run it by opening the executable file inside the `/Contents/MacOS` folder.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

#### Tell your command where your myapp.app resides

You need to provide the open command an absolute or relative [path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) to the application, unless the executable is already within your [$PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), or you change your working directory to the location in the filesystem where your myapp.app is (in my examples, myapp.app is the Applications folder, the home Applications folder, a folder called someotherplace, and the Shared folder, respectively).

```
 open /Applications/myapp.app
 open ~/Applications/myapp.app
 open ../someotherplace/myapp.app
 cd && cd ../Shared/ && open myapp.app
```

You can also type your open command and hit spacebar, and drag your application from anywhere into the Terminal, and the path will be provided.

#### There is another way

You can execute your executable using its full path  and adding the ampersand.  This will run it in the background so your terminal isn't tied up:

```
 ./myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp &
 /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp &
 cd /Volumes/externaldisk/projects/thisone/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS && ./myapp &
```

And interestingly, using this method you can launch as many instances of your app as you have memory to do so.

#### To use torify with your myapp.app

I'm reasonably sure you need to launch it like this to use torify (assuming your myapp.app is in the /Applications folder):

```
 torify /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp &
```

or

```
 cd /Applications/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/
 torify myapp &
```

Comment: I did not mean that `myapp` cannot run from terminal. The thing is that if I run `myapp` using the `open` command it won't run behind the Tor proxy. By the way, it does not run correctly when I open it using the binary file inside the `/Contents/MacOS/` folder.

Comment: I edited my question to be more understandable.

Comment: brew doesn't show a formula for torify, did they removed it?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. `open` launches the program in the background, so Torify doesn't work. The solution is to start the app by directly invoking its binary. Here's how:

```
torify /Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```